# Unexpected result in Merge Sort for linked list (JAVA)

Tags: java

```java
class Node {

    int data;
    Node next;

    public Node(int a) {data = a; next = null;}
}

public class List {

    public Node head;

    public List () {
        head = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == null;
    }

    public void insertAtFront(int a) {
        Node node = new Node(a);
        node.next = head;
        head = node;
    }

    public void insertAtEnd(int a) {
        Node node = new Node(a);
        // this check cannot be omitted
        // otherwise you get NullPointerException on an empty list.
        if (head == null) {
            insertAtFront(a);
            return;
        }
        Node cur = head;
        while(cur.next != null) {
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        cur.next = node;
    }

    public void insertAfter(Node node, int a) {
        Node newNode = new Node(a);
        if (node == null) {
            System.out.println("Oops...");
            return;
        }
        newNode.next = node.next;
        node.next = newNode;
    }

    public Node search(int a) {
        Node cur = head;
        while(cur != null && cur.data != a) cur = cur.next;
        return cur;
    }

    public int deleteFirst() {
        if (head == null) {
            System.out.println("Oops...");
            return -1;
        }
        Node node = head;
        head = head.next;
        node.next = null;
        return node.data;
    }

    public int deleteLast() {
        if (head == null || head.next == null)
            return deleteFirst();
        Node second = head;
        Node cur = second.next;
        // when the thile loop finishes,
        // cur points to the last node.
        while(cur.next != null) {
            second = cur;
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        second.next = null;
        return cur.data;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Node cur = head;
        while(cur != null) {
            sb.append(cur.data);
            if (cur.next != null) sb.append(", ");
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private Node merge(Node head1, Node head2) {
        Node dummy = new Node(0);
        Node tail = dummy;
        while (head1 != null && head2 != null) {
            if (head1.data < head2.data) {
                tail.next = head1;
                head1 = head1.next;
            } else {
                tail.next = head2;
                head2 = head2.next;
            }
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        if (head1 != null) {
            tail.next = head1;
        } else {
            tail.next = head2;
        }

        return dummy.next;
    }

    public Node mergesort(Node head) {
        if (head == null || head.next == null) {
            return head;
        }

        Node mid = findMiddle(head);
        Node right = mergesort(mid.next);
        mid.next = null;
        Node left = mergesort(head);

        return merge(left, right);
    }

    private Node findMiddle(Node head) {
        Node slow = head, fast = head.next;
        while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
            fast = fast.next.next;
            slow = slow.next;
        }
        return slow;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list = new List();
        list.insertAtFront(37);
        list.insertAtFront(99);
        list.insertAtFront(12);
        // the list at page 88 of the slides.
        System.out.println(list);
        list.insertAtFront(75);
        System.out.println(list);
        list.insertAtEnd(38);
        System.out.println(list);
        list.insertAfter(list.search(12), 85);
        System.out.println(list);
        list.mergesort(list.head);
        System.out.println("after sorting: " + list + "\n");
        System.out.println("delete the first, which is " + list.deleteFirst());
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("delete the last, which is " + list.deleteLast());
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Here is my code for linked list in merge sort. However, only the rear part of the linked list was displayed. what is the problem....?

Using Intellij:

12, 99, 37

75, 12, 99, 37

75, 12, 99, 37, 38

75, 12, 85, 99, 37, 38

after sorting: 75, 85, 99

delete the first, which is 75

85, 99

delete the last, which is 99

85

Comment: `head` is never updated in `merge` or `mergesort`. That is why is you still start at the same node after sorting.

Comment: @KompjoeFriek I don't get it. Isn't my findMiddle updating the head recursively?

Comment: No. `findMiddle` does not update anything. Also: i was referring to `List.head`, not the parameter of the function(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while getting return from mergesort() in main method you are not changing the head of the list there.
So in your case the list is sorted but head remains 75 only and thing work right according to the code

In main method 
Replace:  list.mergesort(list.head);
with:  list.head = list.mergesort(list.head);

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code, see below. Hopefully it's pretty self explanatory.

```
public class List {

    public Node head;

    public List () {
        head = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == null;
    }

    public void insertAtFront(int a) {
        Node node = new Node(a);
        node.next = head;
        head = node;
    }

    public void insertAtEnd(int a) {
        Node node = new Node(a);
        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
        }
        else {
            Node cur = head;
            while(cur.next != null) {
                cur = cur.next;
            }
            cur.next = node;
        }
    }

    public void insertAfter(Node predecessor, int a) {
        if (predecessor == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Predecessor cannot be null");
        }
        Node node = new Node(a);
        node.next = predecessor.next;
        predecessor.next = node;
    }

    /** returns null if a is not found */
    public Node findFirst(int a) {
        Node cur = head;
        while(cur != null && cur.data != a) {
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return cur;
    }

    public int removeFirst() {
        if (head == null) {              
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot remove from empty list");
        }
        Node node = head;
        head = head.next;
        node.next = null;
        return node.data;
    }

    public int removeLast() {
        if (head == null || head.next == null) {
            return removeFirst();
        }
        Node cur = head;
        while(cur.next.next != null) {
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        int data = cur.next.data;
        cur.next = null;
        return data;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[");
        Node cur = head;
        while(cur != null) {
            sb.append(cur.data);
            if (cur.next != null) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private Node merge(Node head1, Node head2) {
        Node dummy = new Node(0);
        Node tail = dummy;
        while (head1 != null && head2 != null) {
            if (head1.data < head2.data) {
                tail.next = head1;
                head1 = head1.next;
            } else {
                tail.next = head2;
                head2 = head2.next;
            }
            tail = tail.next;
        }
        if (head1 != null) {
            tail.next = head1;
        } else {
            tail.next = head2;
        }
        return dummy.next;
    }

    public Node mergesort(Node head) {
        if (head == null || head.next == null) {
            return head;
        }
        Node mid = findMiddle(head);
        Node right = mergesort(mid.next);
        mid.next = null;
        Node left = mergesort(head);
        return merge(left, right);
    }

    private Node findMiddle(Node head) {
        Node slow = head, fast = head.next;
        while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
            fast = fast.next.next;
            slow = slow.next;
        }
        return slow;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list = new List();
        list.insertAtFront(37);
        list.insertAtFront(99);
        list.insertAtFront(12);

        // the list at page 88 of the slides.
        System.out.println(list);

        list.insertAtFront(75);
        System.out.println(list);

        list.insertAtEnd(38);
        System.out.println(list);

        list.insertAfter(list.search(12), 85);
        System.out.println(list);

        list.head = list.mergesort(list.head);
        System.out.println("after sorting: " + list + "\n");

        System.out.println("delete the first, which is " + list.deleteFirst());
        System.out.println(list);

        System.out.println("delete the last, which is " + list.deleteLast());
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Returning -1 for failed removal is a bad idea since you are not preventing negative numbers as actual data.